Water got on electric circuits, new breakers for circuits does not fix them
When I was turning the water on in my house this spring, there was an accident and an open water pipe released water that shorted out the lights and several other outlets in the living room.
I let it dry out and then changed the circuit breakers to that light and those outlets. 2 were affected. It still does not work. What to do next?

Unless the breakers/panel got wet, it is unlikely they are the problem.  Turning off the power/breakers and check the outlets/lights will find the problem.  Either loose wires or something in the outlets/lights themselves.

Welcome! The circuit breaker replacement work should be checked to verify it was done correctly. Next the condition of the lights and outlets could be checked. Perhaps you could edit your question and include more detail (photos, for example) so we can focus on helping you verify the circuit breaker installation is correctly done.

What made you think the circuit breakers needed to be replaced? Did the water pour onto the circuit breaker panel? Or onto the electric wiring on the living room?

There is a chance that a GFCI opened and everything downstream will not be powered.

Similar to @RMDman's comment: are there any GFCI outlets in the living room or elsewhere? They will have a 'test' and reset' button on them. I once had a problem like this after a flooding incident. It took me a while to figure out that the issue was a GFCI outlet that was upstairs and a room over.  Even if it didn't get wet, it will still flip if anything it protects had a ground fault (this is a good thing.)

You haven't given much information about your situation, so the only suggestions I can give are similarly vague.

Make sure your outlet and switch boxes are completely dry
Check for short circuits, burnt/singed or other visibly electrically damaged wiring and equipment in those boxes
Replace the outlets, light switches, and any other gear in those boxes

If none of these resolve the issue, you need to inspect the wiring inside the walls by removing it, which will make it easier to replace the wiring when you find the fault.

Can you check for water inside wiring by inspection?  AIUI, water can get deep into wires by capillary action, and is almost impossible to remove.

No, but a dead short could have visible evidence of arcing. If the fault isn't in the switches or outlets, by elimination it's got to be in the cables.

check that none of the connections have corroded
